# The FormBuilder field that is not validated is still required by angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a very simple html template page and the component displaying the page:

My html page:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="mb-3 col-3">
    <label>Group</label>
    <input type="text" #data matInput formControlName="cleanerGroup" matInput placeholder="Specify a group"
      oninput="this.value = this. value.toUpperCase()" required />
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <button type="button" (click)="onAddSchedule()" class="btn btn-primary"
        [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': !form.controls['scheduledDate'].valid}">
         Add
    </button>
    &nbsp;
</div>
</form>
```

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  title = 'NoRequiredTest';
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      cleanerGroup: ['',  /*[this.isCleaner ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator, this.isCleaner ? Validators.minLength(1) : Validators.nullValidator] */],
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.form.controls; }

  onAddSchedule() {

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      var err1 = this.f['scheduledDate'].errors;
      var err2 = this.f['cleanerGroup'].errors;
      var err3 = this.f['function'].errors;

      var val1 = this.f['scheduledDate'].valid;
      var val2 = this.f['cleanerGroup'].valid;
      var val3 = this.f['function'].valid;

      var err = this.form.getError;
      console.log(this.form.errors);
      if (this.f['cleanerGroup'].invalid) {

        var ctrl = this.form.get('cleanerGroup');
        var err1 = this.f['cleanerGroup'].errors;
        console.log(err1);
      }
      this.f['cleanerGroup'].updateValueAndValidity();
      this.form.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

My problem is that the `if (this.form.invalid)`  always seems to be true.
Although I don't have any validation handler specified for the field `cleanerGroup` in the above code my form is invalid saying (in debugger) that the field `required` is `true`.
What am I missing?

Comment: don't use `required` in html